# msysgit32 insists on launching from HOMEDRIVE/HOMEPATH

Tags: git

Even if I set the HOME environment variable explicitly, git bash insists in launching with default folder HOMEDRIVE/HOMEPATH which is a network folder.

Is there a way to override this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out

The issue was with the shortcut to Git Bash - "start in folder" set to `%HOMEDRIVE%`...